# Why isnt this ajax live search working

Tags: php, jquery

****Updated code as of 3-28**

*Index.php*

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>jQuery Search Demonstration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".keywords").keyup(function(){
                $('#key').html($(this).val());
                $('#table').html($('.table:checked').val());

                // Do the ajax call
                // Get the textbox value: $(this).val()
                // Get the radio value: $('.table:checked').val()

                /*$.post("search.php", { keywords: $(".keywords").val() }, function(data){
                    $("div#content").empty()
                    $.each(data, function(){
                        $("div#content").append("- <a href='prof.php?pID=" + this.pID + "'>" + this.last + "</a>");
                    });
                }, "json");*/
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Search by:
    <input type="radio" name="table" class="table" value="Table 1" />Professor<br />
    <input type="radio" name="table" class="table" value="Table 2" />Department<br />
    <input type="radio" name="table" class="table" value="Table 3" />Course<br />

    <input type="text" name="search" class="keywords">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="search">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

*Search.php*

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('##',"##","##");
mysql_select_db("###", $link);

$keywords = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["keywords"] );

$query = mysql_query("SELECT pID, lname, fname 
                                    FROM Professor 
                                    WHERE CONCAT(lname,fname) LIKE '%". $keywords . "%'");

$arr = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $query ) )
{
    $arr[] = array( "pID" => $row["pID"], "last" => $row["lname"], "first" => $row["fname "] );
}

echo json_encode( $arr );
?>
```

*Sql for each selection:*
[Professor]

```
SELECT pID, lname, fname 
                                    FROM Professor 
                                    WHERE CONCAT(lname,fname) LIKE '%". $keywords . "%'";
```

[Department]

```
SELECT prefix, code 
                                    FROM Department 
                                    WHERE name LIKE '%". $keywords . "%'";
```

[course]

SELECT prefix, code 
                                    FROM Course 
                                    WHERE CONCAT(prefix,course) LIKE '%". $keywords . "%'";

Comment: Do you get an error message? Do you get any results back from search.php?

Comment: your query will fail, singe quote no matching end quote, the LIKE keywords wont work for multiple words ...

Comment: Dagon, adding a single quote does nothing. Just tried it. You're talking LIKE '%**'**" right?

Comment: see below, but that only matches a single word, if they enter several your going to have to split them up

Comment: explode on space, loop, write valid querry

Comment: Your new javascript have syntax error. Any missing datatype "json" in the post() function. Please check my answer for correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your query like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT pID, lname, fname 
                                    FROM Professor 
                                    WHERE CONCAT(lname,fname) LIKE '%". $keywords . "%'");
```

Please make sure this these fields in json and javascript are the same:

```
$arr[] = array( "id" => $row["pID"], "last" => $row["lname"], "first" => $row["fname"] );

$("div#content").append("- <a href='post.php?id=" + this.id + "'>" + this.first + " " + this.last + "</a>");
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>jQuery Search Demonstration</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".keywords").keyup(function(){
        getData();
    });
    $(".table").click(function(){
        getData();
    });
});

function getData(){
    $.post("search.php", 
        {
            keywords: $(".keywords").val(),
            table: $('.table:checked').val()
        }, 
        function(data){
            $("div#content").empty();
            var phppage;
            switch($('.table:checked').val())
            {
                case 'professor': 
                    phppage = 'prof';
                    break;
                case 'department': 
                    phppage = 'department';
                    break;
                case 'course': 
                    phppage = 'course';
                    break;
            } 

            $.each(data, function(){
                $("div#content").append("- <a href='" + phppage + ".php?pID=" + this.id + "'>" + this.name + "</a>");
            });
        },
        "json");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Search by:
<input type="text" name="search" class="keywords" /><br />

<input type="radio" name="table" class="table" value="professor" checked="checked" /> Professor<br />
<input type="radio" name="table" class="table" value="department" /> Department<br />
<input type="radio" name="table" class="table" value="course" /> Course<br />

<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost',"#","#");
mysql_select_db("#", $link);

$arr = array();
$keywords = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["keywords"] );
switch ($_POST["table"])
{
    case 'professor';
        $arr = getProfessor($keywords);
        break;
    case 'department';
        $arr = getDepartment($keywords);
        break;
    case 'course';
        $arr = getCourse($keywords);
        break;
}

echo json_encode( $arr );

function getProfessor($keywords){
    $arr = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT pID, lname, fname 
                            FROM Professor 
                            WHERE CONCAT(lname,fname) LIKE '%". $keywords . "%'");

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $query ) )
    {
        $arr[] = array( "id" => $row["pID"], "name" => $row["fname"] . ' ' . $row["lname"]);
    }

    return $arr;
}

function getDepartment($keywords){
    $arr = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT prefix, code 
                            FROM Department 
                            WHERE name LIKE '%". $keywords . "%'");

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $query ) )
    {
        $arr[] = array( "id" => $row["code"], "name" =>  $row["code"]);
    }

    return $arr;
}

function getCourse($keywords){
    $arr = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT prefix, code 
                            FROM Course 
                            WHERE CONCAT(prefix,course) LIKE '%". $keywords . "%'");

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $query ) )
    {
        $arr[] = array( "id" => $row["code"], "name" => $row["code"]);
    }

    return $arr;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you check there is any javascript error? Did you get the response from server? Please use Firebug to check your request and response.

Comment: YNHat - I took a screenshot at http://postimage.org/image/1bdiy0eqs/ it does not show errors on JS in firebug lite.

Comment: I found other error in your query. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: I tested the code with my database and it works for me. I updated my answer with the working code. Please check you ajax request and response in Firebug to check whether is the problem, Javascript or PHP.

Comment: @YNhat - I have added my most update to date code, it still is just showing nothing at all. I showed the input I put in and still nothing is showing. I double checked the db field names as well...

Comment: Can you check the ajax request and response in Firebug?

Comment: Ynhat - JSLint said: Error:
Problem at line 5 character 41: Expected ';' and instead saw '$'.

$("div#content").empty()

Implied global: $ 2,3,4,5,7, document 2

Comment: you are missing semicolon at that line, but it's not important. The most inportant is identifying which part causes problem. Please check in the Firebug, "Net" tab to see whether the request is sent and you get the response back or not. Please use the Full Firebug version, not Firebug Lite. I think the "Net" tab doesnt exist in Firebug Lite.

Comment: It doesnt look like there is being a request sent at all.

Comment: I checked in Firefox, Firebug, the only request is the request for the Ajax library from Google.

Comment: When you click "Submit" button, is there any request?

Comment: @YNhat - No there still is no request at all. I've included a screenshot above. Could there be an error with the ajax in making the whole request?

Comment: Hi, I got your problem. You didnt run your html file on a web server. Therefore it cannot make any request. The html and php page must be same domain. You can test will your localhost web server as well. I also have an error in php file. It's missing the $query variable. I updated my answer.

Comment: YNHat - Great! That works. Anyway we can make it so they dont have to click submit? It just generates on the fly, asynchronously?

Comment: How do I implement this, based on various fields , so for example if user clicks "By Professor", or "By Department", etc. radio buttons. Could you show me this? This is working great so far though! Thanks!

Comment: I yoy dont want to click on submit button, you can capture the event onkeyup of the textbox. You can pass the checked value of the radio into ajax call. Based on that value, you can use the appropriate table. Here is the idea how to do it. http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/mXwet/1/

Comment: Please see updated code, implemented your jsfiddle not seeing anything.

Comment: I figured out that you dont know what the code is doing. My above comment just an idea how you get the textbox and radio value when you enter the value. It's not a working code. I updated my answer and I hope it works for you. However, I suggest that you go through every single line of codes and understand what it does. It will help you.

Comment: YNHat - I do understand what this code is doing. I have trouble generating it all.

Comment: YNhat - Outstanding support! I've fixed this myself! Thank you SOO much!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your javascript you're trying to access the .id and .title properties of the returned json objects but they don't exist from the array you create in php

```
$arr[] = array( "id" => $row["pID"], "title" => $row["lname"]." ".$row["fname"] );
```

Does that work?

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search").click(function(){
        $.post("search.php", { keywords: $(".keywords").val() }, function(data){
            $("div#content").empty()
            $.each(data, function(){
                $("div#content").append("- <a href='post.php?id=" + this.id + "'>" + this.first + " " + this.last + "</a>");
    });
});
```

Looks like that is missing a closing brace to enclose the $.each

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search").click(function(){
        $.post("search.php", { keywords: $(".keywords").val() }, function(data){
            $("div#content").empty()
            $.each(data, function(){
                $("div#content").append("- <a href='post.php?id=" + this.id + "'>" + this.first + " " + this.last + "</a>");
            });
    });
});
```